# vue.js vue-gl missing props camera in component

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I installed Vue-gl in my app.js as

```
const { VglRenderer, VglScene } = require('vue-gl');
Object.keys(VueGL).forEach((name) => Vue.component(name, VueGL[name]));
```

Then in my parent component I have a child component:

```
   <scene :positionItem="positionItem"></scene>
   import scene from "./../components/scene";
```

Having this code:

```
export default {
    name: "configurator",

  components :{
    scene
  },

   data: function(){
      return {
        positionItem: -4,
      }
   },

  methods:{
    updatePosition(){
      this.$root.$emit("input", {
        positionItem :this.$refs.positionItem.value
      })
    }

  },

  mounted() {
      this.$root.$on('input', data => {
        this.positionItem = data;
      });

  }
}
```

The child component "scene" is

```
<template>

<vgl-renderer >
  <vgl-sphere-geometry name="sphere"></vgl-sphere-geometry>
  <vgl-scene name="main">
    <!-- Re-rendering will be triggered when zCoordinate changes. -->
    <vgl-mesh :position="`0 0 ${positionItem}`" geometry="sphere"></vgl-mesh>
  </vgl-scene>
  <vgl-perspective-camera orbit-position="12 0 0" name="camera"></vgl-perspective-camera>
</vgl-renderer>
```

```
<script lang="ts">

export default {
  props: ["positionItem"],
  data: function () {
    return {
    }
  },
 }
</script>
```

The renders works but I got 2 errors about missing props camera and scene:

> vue.esm.js?efeb:628 [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "camera"
>
> found in
>
> ---> 
>           at src/components/scene.vue
>             at src/components/configurator.vue
>               at src/App.vue

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. The vgl-renderer component needs to be given a name and a screne property of type string. These components must be present in the scene with the same names. Otherwise vue-gl will throw another error. I can't find anything about these required properties on the vue-gl documentation. Maybe it's outdated. I managed to get it working like this ...

```
<template>
  <vgl-renderer 
    camera= "camera"
    scene= "scene"
    class="getting-started"
  >
    <vgl-box-geometry name="box"></vgl-box-geometry>
    <vgl-scene name="scene">
      <vgl-mesh geometry="box"></vgl-mesh>
    </vgl-scene>
    <vgl-perspective-camera name="camera" orbit-position="3 1 0.5"></vgl-perspective-camera>
  </vgl-renderer>
</template>

<script>
  const { VglRenderer, VglScene, VglBoxGeometry, VglMesh, VglPerspectiveCamera } = require('vue-gl'); 
  export default {
    components : {
      VglRenderer, VglScene, VglBoxGeometry, VglMesh, VglPerspectiveCamera
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The docs list `name` as a required prop for `VglCamera`: https://vue-gl.github.io/components/cameras/vgl-camera.html#props